# Moving the current window to another desktop only with keyboard and mouse

Tags: macos

By desktop I don't mean like desktop on an external monitor, I just mean the virtual desktops that Mac provides
The mouse I am using is also a PC mouse, so not a Magic mouse or track pad.
The keyboard tho, it is the Apple keyboard.

So How Can I move the active window to another desktop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the window at the top so you can move it around the screen. Then move your cursor, while still holding and dragging the window, against the side towards the desktop you want to move it to. After a short pause the desktop will change a the window is now on another desktop.

In something more succinct:

1. Grab the window in desktop 1 with cursor
2. Use cursor to drag the window over against the right side of the screen (so you can't move the cursor any further to the right)
3. After a short delay the desktop will change to Desktop 2
4. Release the window.

Comment: ah I see... basically it is like drag it as much as you can and "WAIT" like two seconds until OS makes sure you really want to move it to another desktop and it will do it.

Comment: @BDotA, That is exactly right. I find myself using this method more than Mission Control.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Mission Control for this. Press the mission control key (F3 without pressing fn) and then drag the windows you want onto the desktops you want.

You can also open mission control by swiping up with 4 fingers on a trackpad or double tapping with 2 fingers on an apple mouse.